# Difference between UIBarButtonItem properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

What's the difference between:

```
myBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

and

```
myBarButtonItem.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Does the button become gray each time?

Comment: I second this question with this addition: what happens when you set one of these to `YES` and the other to `NO`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the apple documentation uibarbuttonitem does not posses userInteractionEnabled property.Since it inherits from UIBarItem Class Reference it also does not have userInteractionEnabled property.

And also if you use this line `myBarButtonItem.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`
your *app will crash*.

If you dont want your button to get pressed use this:-`myBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;`
Also see apple documentation.

For the regular Button:-

myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO; will cause no effect in your image image and you can not press it also.

myButton.enabled = NO; will cause the shadow to come on your button image and you can not press it also.

Comment: What about for a regular UIButton?

Comment: I just discovered this myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I feel like I should have known all of this long ago. Wish I could vote you up again.

Answer (score 5):

I read through the documentation, and here are my findings.

`UIButton` inherits from `UIControl` the boolean property `enabled`

> A Boolean value that determines
>   whether the receiver is enabled.
>
> Specify YES to make the control
>   enabled; otherwise, specify NO to make
>   it disabled. The default value is YES.
>   If the enabled state is NO, the
>   control ignores touch events and
>   subclasses may draw differently.

`UIControl` inherits from `UIView` the boolean property `userInteractionEnabled`:

> A Boolean value that determines
>   whether user events are ignored and
>   removed from the event queue.
>
> When set to NO, user events—such as
>   touch and keyboard—intended for the
>   view are ignored and removed from the
>   event queue. When set to YES, events
>   are delivered to the view normally.
>   The default value is YES.

From this I conclude

- `button.userInteractionEnabled = NO` means the button looks normal but doesn't respond to touches (from the `UIView` inheritance).
- `button.enabled = NO` means the button is grayed out and doesn't respond to touches (from the `UIControl` inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

`UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have a property called `userInteractionEnabled`, only `UIView` and it's subclasses have that property.

So, in short,

```
myBarButtonItem.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

wouldn't grey out the button, it would crash your program.

Setting the `enabled` property to `NO`, however, *will* grey out the button.

Comment: I think Gypsa covered this already. Any thoughts about regular `UIButton`s?

Comment: UIButtons are subclasses of `UIView` so you can set the `userInteractionEnabled` property and the button will ignore touch events, but I don't know if it will draw differently. Setting `enabled` to `NO` will grey out the button and make ignore touch events.

Comment: "it would crash your program" is largely inaccurate, because it would be no accidental feat to get it to compile in the first place.